# send/receive messages from my android application to chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, web, mobile, chrome-remote-debugging

I am trying to establish a connection between my android application and chrome on android. I am using LocalSocket for socket communication as below:

```
        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
        request.put("method", "Page.reload");
        LocalSocket s = new LocalSocket();
    try {
        s.connect(new LocalSocketAddress("chrome_devtools_remote", LocalSocketAddress.Namespace.ABSTRACT));
        Log.i("Chrome: ", "After local socket connect");
        //StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder().append("GET /json HTTP/1.0\r\n");
        OutputStream oss = s.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = jo.toString().getBytes("utf-8");
        oss.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        Log.i("Chrome: ", "outbuf size " + Integer.toString(s.getSendBufferSize()));
        InputStream iss = s.getInputStream();
        Integer i;
        String res = "";
        while ((i = iss.read()) != -1) {
            res += i.toString();
        }
        Log.i("Chrome: ", res);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", "Connecting Local Socket "+e.toString());
    }
```

I am able to establish the connection between Chrome and my App, but I am not able to send and receive messages to automate page loads in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome does not allow every app to connect to the devtool socket.
It makes sure the connecting app is either signed with the same key or the user is *root* or *shell*. The source code for this security logic can be found [here](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/browser/android/devtools_auth.cc).

In case the security check fails it prints the following message, which you should see in logcat:

> DevTools: connection attempt from